# Collectable object doesn't work once I prefab it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a collectable object which has another object as a child that has a particle system attached. When the player runs into the collectable  object, the collectable should be destroyed and the particle system should play. The following code WORKS correctly when the game object is placed  the scene but as soon as I prefab it and instantiate it in code - the particle system no longer works.

Any ideas? Cheers!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class collectable : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject birdParticleObject; 
    ParticleSystem birdParticlesystem; 


    void Start () {

        birdParticleObject = GameObject.Find("BirdParticleSystem");
        birdParticlesystem = birdParticleObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Player") {

            birdParticlesystem.Play();
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: What GameObject you prefab and instantiate, the collectable or the birdParticleObject?

Comment: are you using public variables and linking them to the things in the scene?  don't forget that you cannot "put in a prefab" any link to your scene.  (of course, the prefab does not know about a scene - it could be in a different game altogether tomorrow!)

Comment: Although, Prefab can't have any persistent reference to a scene object, but it can have to its own objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the area that says:

```
birdParticlesystem.Play();
Destroy(gameObject);
```

You're telling the particle system to play and then immediately destroying it's parent which will also destroys it. Try:

```
     birdParticlesystem.Play();
     birdParticlesystem.transform.SetParent(null);
     Destroy(gameObject);
```

This will remove the particle system from it's parent before destroying the collectible object. You should then `Destroy()` the particle system once it's done playing, otherwise it will be left in the scene.